# SQL Server stored procedure reducing amount of memory granted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Execution Plan Download Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3spvo46541bf6p1/Execution%20plan.xml?dl=0

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a pretty complex stored procedure that's requesting way too much memory upon execution. Here's a screenshot of the execution plan:

http://s15.postimg.org/58ycuhyob/image.png

The underlying query probably needs a lot of tuning as indicated by massive number of estimated rows, but that's besides the point. Regardless of the complexity of the query, it should not be requesting **3 gigabytes of memory** upon execution.

**How do I prevent this behavior?** I've tried the following:

- DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear plan cache. This accomplished nothing.
- Setting RECOMPILE option on both SP and SQL level. Again, this does nothing.
- Messing around with MAXDOP option, from 0 to 8. Same issue.

The query returns about ~1k rows on average, and it does look into a table with more than 3 million rows with about 4 tables being joined. Executing the query returns the result in less than 3 seconds in majority of the cases.

Edit:

One more thing, using query hints is not really viable for this case since the parameters vary greatly for our case.

Edit2:

Uploaded execution plan upon request

Edit3:

I've tried rebuilding/reorganizing fragmented indices. Apparently, there were few but nothing too serious. Anyhow, this didn't reduce the amount of memory granted and didn't reduce the number of estimated rows (If this is somehow related).

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement? And upload the plan XML?

Comment: @MartinSmith Unfortuantely, due to NDA I'm not allowed to post the SQL statement. The plan XML, I can upload after I've redacted database name/schema etc. I'll upload it asap.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding/reorganizing indexes and updating statistics? Do you have a plan that shows the actual rows returned. Right now it shows the estimated rows are over 89 million.

Comment: @JodyT No, I haven't tried rebuilding/reorganizing indices. I will try this on our test db. Actual # of rows returned is 100. Still, I'm having a very hard time grasping why something like this causes a large amount of memory being requested each time the stored procedure is ran.

Comment: You might consider breaking this up so a partial result is materialized into a temp table and it then has accurate row estimates for the rest. What are the cross joins with no join predicate about? Are there no join predicates in the source?

Comment: @MartinSmith There's one part where join is a bit funny. It's emulating a "conditional" join from abusing OR operator, so the tables are joined based on what parameter is passed into the stored procedure. I'm assuming the large number of estimated rows come from that.

But regardless of the cause, I'm still baffled as to why this could possibly cause 3 gigabytes of memory grant. Is there no way of preventing this behavior?

Comment: In SSMS, click 'include actual execution plan' and run your query. Do the estimated and actual rowcounts vary wildly?

Answer (score 0):

You say optimizing the query is besides the point, but actually it's actually just the point. When a query is executed, SQL Server will -after generating the execution plan- reserve the memory needed for executing the query. The more rows intermediate results are estimated to hold the more memory is estimated to be required.

So, rewrite your query and/or create new indexes to get a decent query plan. A quick glance at the query plan shows some nested loops without join predicates and a number of table scans of which probably only a few records are used.